# As the search clean leave if they leave all Swift users down on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a TableView in the main storyboard, to search for users but what happens is when I enter the part of looking down the search bar I load all users without me put anything what I would like is to remove these users and me users go when I begins to look not when, entered the part of the user search leave my UITableViewController code and an image.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class usersVC: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

    // declare search bar
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()

    // tableView arrays to hold information from server
    var usernameArray = [String]()
    var avaArray = [PFFile]()




    // default func
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // implement search bar
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
        searchBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 34
        let searchItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchItem

        // call functions
        loadUsers()

    }



    // SEARCHING CODE
    // load users function
    func loadUsers() {

        let usersQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        usersQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        usersQuery.limit = 20
        usersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                // clean up
                self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.avaArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                // found related objects
                for object in objects! {
                    self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)
                    self.avaArray.append(object.valueForKey("ava") as! PFFile)
                }

                // reload
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

    }


    // search updated
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        // find by username
        let usernameQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        usernameQuery.whereKey("username", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + searchBar.text!)
        usernameQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                // if no objects are found according to entered text in usernaem colomn, find by fullname
                if objects!.isEmpty {

                    let fullnameQuery = PFUser.query()
                    fullnameQuery?.whereKey("username", matchesRegex: "(?i)" + self.searchBar.text!)
                    fullnameQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            // clean up
                            self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                            self.avaArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                            // found related objects
                            for object in objects! {
                                self.usernameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                                self.avaArray.append(object.objectForKey("ava") as! PFFile)
                            }

                            // reload
                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }
                    })
                }

                // clean up
                self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.avaArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                // found related objects
                for object in objects! {
                    self.usernameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                    self.avaArray.append(object.objectForKey("ava") as! PFFile)
                }

                // reload
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        })

        return true
    }


    // tapped on the searchBar
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // hide collectionView when started search

        // show cancel button
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }


    // clicked cancel button
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // unhide collectionView when tapped cancel button

        // dismiss keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // hide cancel button
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

        // reset text
        searchBar.text = ""

        // reset shown users
        loadUsers()
    }



    // TABLEVIEW CODE
    // cell numb
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return usernameArray.count
    }

    // cell height
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.size.width / 4
    }

    // cell config
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // define cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! followersCell

        cell.avaImg.image = nil

        // hide follow button
        cell.followBtn.hidden = true

        // connect cell's objects with received infromation from server
        cell.usernameLbl.text = usernameArray[indexPath.row]
        avaArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                cell.avaImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }

        return cell
    }


    // selected tableView cell - selected user
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // calling cell again to call cell data
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! followersCell

        // if user tapped on his name go home, else go guest
        if cell.usernameLbl.text! == PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
            let home = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeVC") as! homeVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(home, animated: true)
        } else {
            guestname.append(cell.usernameLbl.text!)
            let guest = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("guestVC") as! guestVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(guest, animated: true)
        }
    }





    // cell line spasing
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    // cell inter spasing
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }



    // scrolled down
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // scroll down for paging
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height / 6 {

        }
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. I've improved your question a bit. :) Please don't hesitate to use the [edit] button to improve it further: for example, the title is not very clear. Thanks!